# Is there a software that can simulate an input device (game controller) on Windows?

Tags: windows, game-controller, input-device, simulation

For a scientific experiment I want to control a driving simulation to make the car constantly go a certain speed. This requires a fixed input from an input device like a gaming pedal (say 80% force). I guess keyboard simulation would not be enough since keys can only be on or off and the amount of pressure is not measured as with a gaming controller.

I'm looking for an application that allows me to set the constant input, a (simulated) game controller sends to the computer. Any suggestions on implementing it myself would also be welcome.

Comment: I recommend that you check out http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software .

Comment: Sorry, software recommendation questions are off topic here. Check out the Beta http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/